# Incomplete argument (or error) in article on unital ring extensions?

Tags: ring-theory

In the paper
[Commutative rngs](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Dan-Anderson/publication/304199755_Commutative_rngs/links/5769534608ae2d7145ba7e26/Commutative-rngs.pdf) by Dan Anderson, Section 2 'Adjunction of an Identity', the second paragraph says:

'Let A be a commutative [Ann: associative, unital or not] ring containing a regular element r₀. Let N be the set of regular elements (that is, nonzero divisors) of A. Then A<sub>N</sub>=T/(A) the total quotient ring of A has an identity element, namely 1=r₀/r₀. Now A*=A[1]={a+m1|a∊A, m∊ℤ} is a commutative ring with identity. So A ⊆ A* is a unital extension.'

How to embed A in T(A) in the first place ? (Embedding is obligatory, otherwise A[1] not well defined.) *If* N has a multiplicative idempotent d of A, that is d=d², then it's clear how to embed A in T(A): Via the map m≔ A → T(A), x ↦ x/d. m is a ring monomorphism. What if there's no idempotent in N?

Comment: Any particular reason why you find the answer helpful enough to accept, but not helpful enough to upvote? It would appear that you have only ever cast 2 votes, over a period of almost 20 months in which you have asked three questions and posted 3 answers... With 41 reputation, you can certainly upvote things you find helpful.

Comment: True. What I had in mind was existence of a particularly 'simple' representation of x in Aɴ. As it turns out, such a representation exists iff N has idempotent d. Because then xd/d becomes xd/d²=x/d.

Comment: Not sure why you think that $\frac{xd}{d}$ is any less simple than $\frac{x}{d}$... Especially as $\frac{xd}{d}$ "looks like" it should equal $x$, whereas $\frac{x}{d}$ does not.

Comment: That's why 'simple' is quoted. On the other hand, probably most natural way to represent z∊ℤ in ℚ is z/1, although z·1001/1001=z. I don't wanna argue. And hitherto, I hardly thought about votes and voting, but mostly content. Sorry.

Comment: Yes, but that requires your multiplicative subset to contain $1$ (that is one reason many authors require multiplicative subsets of unital rings to be submonoids, and not merely subsemigroups, so that you can guarantee $1$ in the subset, and then you define the embedding to be $a\mapsto \frac{a}{1}$). But if you start with a rng, then that is not available. I prefer to simply define the embeddings to be as I give them, and then prove they are all the same function; then you can pick whatever $s$ makes things simple for you.

Comment: I appreciate your approach, esp. for educational purposes. In fact, learner may miss the complete picture if exposed solely to the special case of idempotent, or even 1, in N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S$ be a any nonempty subsemigroup of the multiplicative semigroup of $A$ (that is, a "multiplicative subset", and we do not require it to be a monoid or even a submonoid if $A$ has a unity). Recall that the localization $S^{-1}A$ is the set of expressions of the form $\frac{a}{s}$ with $a\in A$ and $s\in S$, under the equivalence relation
$$\frac{a}{s}\sim\frac{b}{t}\iff \exists u\in S\text{ such that } u(at-bs)=0.$$
Addition is defined by $\frac{a}{s}+\frac{b}{t}=\frac{at+bs}{st}$, and multiplication by $\frac{a}{s}\cdot\frac{b}{t}=\frac{ab}{st}$.

For each $s\in S$, let $\varphi_s\colon A\to S^{-1}A$ be given by $\varphi_s=\frac{as}{s}$. I claim that if $s,t\in S$, then $\varphi_s=\varphi_t$. Indeed, for any $a\in A$ we have $(as)t-(at)s=0$ (since $A$ is commutative), so
$$\varphi_s(a) = \frac{as}{s} = \frac{at}{t}=\varphi_t(a).$$
So we can drop the subindex $s$, and simply recall that if $s,t\in S$, then $\frac{as}{s}=\frac{at}{t}$.

I claim that $\varphi$ is a ring homomorphism. Indeed, fix $s\in S$; then $ss\in S$ as well, and we have:
$$\begin{align*}
 \varphi(a+b) &= \frac{(a+b)s}{s} = \frac{(a+b)ss}{ss}\\
&= \frac{(as)s + (bs)s}{ss} = \frac{as}{s}+\frac{bs}{s}\\
&= \varphi(a)+\varphi(b);\\
\varphi(ab) &= \frac{(ab)s}{s} = \frac{(ab)ss}{ss}\\
&= \frac{(as)(bs)}{ss} = \frac{as}{s}\cdot\frac{bs}{s}\\
&= \varphi(a)\varphi(b).
\end{align*}$$

**Claim.** $a\in\ker\varphi$ if and only if there exists $t\in S$ such that $at=0$.

Indeed: if $at=0$ for some $t\in S$, then $\varphi(a) = \frac{at}{t} = \frac{0}{t} = 0_{S^{-1}A}$, so $a\in\ker(\varphi)$.

Conversely, if $a\in\ker(\varphi)$, then $\frac{as}{s} = \frac{0}{s}$. That mean that there exists $u\in S$ such that $u((as)s - 0s) = 0$. That means $a(s^2u)=0$; but $s^2u\in S$, so was can take $t=s^2u$.

This holds for any ring (commutative and associative, whether or not it has a unit, whether or not $S$ contains idempotents).

In the case at hand, $S=N$ is the set of regular elements, that is, elements that are not zero divisors. In particular, for all $a\in A$, if $t\in N$ is such that $at=0$, then $a=0$. That means that $\ker(\varphi)=\{0\}$, so $\varphi$ is an embedding, showing that $A$ embedds into $A_N$, as desired.

Comment: Concerning your definition of equivalence relation ~, why not  simply  x/s ~ y/t ⟺ xt=ys (all x, y∊A and s, t∊S) ?

Comment: @Peterש Because it may fail to be transitive in the case where $S$ contains zero divisors. For example, in the integers modulo $6$, with $S=\{1,2,4\}$. Then $\frac{3}{1}$ would be equivalent to $\frac{0}{2}$, since $3(2) - (0)(1) = 0$ in $A$; and $\frac{0}{2}$ would be equivalent to $\frac{0}{1}$, since $0-0=0$. But $\frac{3}{1}$ is not equivalent to $\frac{0}{1}$ because $3-1$ is not $0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4463501/742). If $S$ does not contain $0$ or zero divisors, the two conditions are equivalent, but this is the general definition.